# Angular2 Router - Looking for routes before Base Href?

Tags: angularjs, routes

**The scenario:**

- There is a CMS behind the site that does routing for the majority of
  the site.
- There is an Angular2 app that controls a certain subsection of    the
  site that is a SPA.
- The Angular2 app uses the built in Angular2    Router to do the
  routing which is working fine, except when trying to    go back out
  of the Angular2 section of the site.
- @angular/core version 2.4.0 (and the others, http, etc.), @angular/router version 3.4.0

For the Angular2 section, the `<base href>` tag is set to the path where the Angular2 is supposed to take over routing (/*culture_code*/*subroute*/*angular_2_section*/*route*)

```
<base href='/*culture_code*/*subroute*/*angular_2_section*/'>
```

The platformBrowserDynamic binding also has the APP_BASE_HREF provide set up with the same url as the `<base href>` tag (I'm not sure if it's necessary to have both but I wanted to make sure it is set).

The problem is that when clicking back in the browser, which would bring the user back to /*culture_code*/*subroute*/*cms_handled_route*, the Route module from Angular is detecting it as an Unknown route (path: '**') and then I'm not sure how to break it out of the Router, since the base href of the routing shouldn't be kicking in at that url. The *cms_handled_route* is at the same level as the *angular_2_section* and the `<base href>` only should start after *angular_2_section*

Since I want it to go back to the CMS routing at that point, I've tried using Location (from @angular/common) to do a back() but it still seems to be stuck.  I tried this by putting it the location.back() in a CanLoad Guard when accessing unknown route, but i'm sure there has to be a better way to do this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Route, CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from "@angular/common";
import { LoggerService } from '@shared2/services/logger.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class RouteUnknownGuard implements CanLoad {
    constructor(private location: Location, private loggerService: LoggerService) {
    }

    canLoad(route: Route): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        this.loggerService.log('Route Unknown - Change to Location routing: ' + this.location.path);
        this.location.back();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there something i'm missing here? Is there an easy way to say to the angular router on Unknown Route, don't do anything?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it turned out the issue wasn't with the Angular2 section of the site, but rather an Angular 1.5 section that the back was going to. The Angular1 section isn't using the routing, but it is using the $locationProvider to update the url without reloading the page, which has an option rewriteLinks that was causing the issue for us.

It was trying to rewrite the link, which was then causing the Angular2 router to say "hey this route doesn't exist" since they are segregated parts of the site, and then we were being trapped in the Angular2 section.  There is more documentation about this setting here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html-link-rewriting under HTML Link rewriting, which we needed to set to false in order to force it to reload the page on Back().  Since we don't use the actual routing capabilities in the Angular 1.5 section, we are able to do this without any apparent side effects so far.

I just wanted to post the solution in case someone else has the same issue.